# OpenGL texture mapping issue

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I'm trying to do texture on my cube as the code below. However, the result that I got is that the image did not cover the entire cube surface while looks like it *looped*.

You can see the blue lining from the picture used:

[image: Capture1]
[image: Capture2]

I've checked the coordinates but doesn't seem to have any error. I check the image size (512x512), it's also the same as I declared when loading the texture. So, I had trouble figuring where is the problem.

```
void square(void) {
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]); //bind our texture to our shape

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(500, -500, -500);       //behind
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(500, 500, -500);
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(-500, 500, -500);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(-500, -500, -500);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, -500, 500);    //front
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, 500, 500);
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, 500, 500);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, -500, 500);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, -500, -500);   //right
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, 500, -500);
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, 500, 500);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, -500, 500);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, -500, 500);   //left
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, 500, 500);
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, 500, -500);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, -500, -500);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, 500, 500);     //top
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, 500, -500);
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, 500, -500);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, 500, 500);
glEnd();

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, -500, -500);   //bottom
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(500, -500, 500);
glTexCoord3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, -500, 500);
glTexCoord3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-500, -500, -500);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

function to load the RAW file:

```
GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename, int width, intbheight)
{
GLuint texture;
unsigned char * data;
FILE * file;
//The following code will read in our RAW file
file = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (file == NULL) return 0;
data = (unsigned char *)malloc(width * height * 3);
fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
fclose(file);
glGenTextures(1, &texture); //generate the texture with the loaded data
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); //bind the textureto it’s array
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,
    GL_MODULATE); //set texture environment parameters
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
    GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
    GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
    GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
    GL_REPEAT);
//Generate the texture
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
free(data); //free the texture
return texture; //return whether it was successful
}
```

Comment: You say you're using a cubemap, but you have `GL_TEXTURE_2D` as the texture type in your code. Which one is it?

Comment: Ya sorry i mean i'm trying to use texture to map the images to my cube. I will reedit my post. So apparently, I'm using texture.

Comment: The rendering code looks ok, assuming you texture[0] to be repeated on 4 sides. What format is the texture file? How do you load it?

Comment: What values are you using for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`?

Comment: Check the file size if your texture. Is it 786432 bytes?

Comment: With `GL_REPEAT`, you would expect the top row (which looks to be light blue sky) to reappear at the bottom. Try `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` if you don't want that.

Comment: @samgak It's 768kb